# Mysql query update

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

i have this piece of code, i can't get to work properly.

```
require_once("../Packages/Connection.php");

        $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["articleText"]);

        $method = $_POST['method'];
        $articleId = $_POST['articleId'];

        if($method == "update")
        {
            mysql_query("UPDATE Articles SET 'text'='".$text."' WHERE 'id'='".$articleId."'") or die(mysql_error());
        }
```

It is annoying me so much, 
This is the error i get - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''text'='tester2' WHERE 'id'='29'' at line 1...

Thank in advance

Comment: I suggest escaping the $articleId as well, since your SQL is not this way. And even better you should use PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: Have you checked the Mysql manual as suggested in the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have 'text' in your SQL...

It should simply be text as is and thats all: (Same thing for ID)

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Articles SET text = '".$text."' WHERE id='".$articleId."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

What you might have confused the "'" with, is the backtick or "`" that escapes characters and are good for reserved keywords...

Comment: Okay thanks :) but i had a friend help me, right after i posted this.. Sorry. Heres the answear mysql_query("UPDATE Articles SET text='$text' WHERE id='$articleId'") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: This is exactly what i posted except that you have used "Variable parsing" inside of a string while i ended the string cleanly. Depends on taste...

Answer (score 0):

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE Articles SET text='".$text."' WHERE id='".$articleId."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   mysql_query("UPDATE Articles SET `text`='".$text."' WHERE `id`='".$articleId."'")
```

Answer (score 0):

First build the query, then execute it:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Articles SET 'text'='".$text."' WHERE 'id'='".$articleId."'";
$r = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$r) {
    echo "Query: ", $sql, "\n";
    echo "Error: ", mysql_error();
    die();
}
```

This will allow you to better review *what exactly* you've send to the database so that you can actually *check the syntax* as was suggested to you by the error message.

Answer (score -2):

you should use this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Articles SET text ={$text} WHERE id ={$articleId}") or die(mysql_error ());
```

Comment: You will get a syntax error with such a query. You need quotes around the text value.